# Is % used in vb.net/sql?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Recently I've come across a sample code given by someone else, it looks like this

```
    SELECT TOP 1 IVSTK_STKID
    FROM IVSTK_TBL
    WHERE IVSTK_STKID LIKE strPrefix + "%"
    ORDER BY IVSTK_STKID Desc
```

What does the '%' mean and what's the use of it? The code was given to me without doing any further explanation and I'm not even sure it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used with `LIKE`, the `%` sign is a wildcard operator.

In this context, it's looking for anything starting with the value of `strPrefix`

Comment: To expand on that: '%' is a wildcard character used with the SQL `LIKE` operator. So it's independent from VB.NET, i.e. the respective C# sample would look literally the same. There are other wildcards, see [SQL LIKE docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)